# Is it normal that the Angular-CLI is much slower in wsl2 than the default powershell?

Tags: angular, windows, angular-cli, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

In my recent projects I was working with Angular and the Angular-CLI and I noticed that basic CLI commands like `ng g c`, `ng serve`, `ng build` etc. take much more time in the wsl2 terminal (using ubuntu 20.04) than on the default powershell.

Any opinions or recommendations how to solve this problem?

Comment: I just upgraded to WSL2 yesterday and I'm experiencing this right now :(

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean with "much more time"? I'm having issues with running `ng serve` (even with `--verbose=true`) as it seems to hang for about five minutes before it continues. It used to work much faster (i.e. a couple of seconds).

Comment: "Any recommendations"... if you can upgrade to real Ubuntu-20.04 instead of WSL2

Answer (score 16):

If your project files are stored on the Windows filesystem and accessed/launched from WSL2, then yes, it's "normal" (or rather, known). The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#exceptions-for-using-wsl-1-rather-than-wsl-2) mention this behavior:

> If you will be using your WSL Linux distribution to access project files on the Windows file system, [...] you will achieve faster performance across the OS files systems by using WSL 1.

I was experiencing the same slowliness with an Angular project using WSL2, and my files where on the Windows filesystem.

> "Any opinions or recommendations how to solve this problem?"

1. In my case, copying the project files from the Windows filesystem to the WSL2 filesystem (e.g. `$HOME/src`) fixed the performance issues. And in this configuration, WSL2 is effectively way faster than WSL1 :)
2. If you need to keep the source in a Windows folder (perhaps due to your development team workflow), then you may want to downgrade to WSL1, assuming you don't need any of WSL2's features.  Keeping both WSL1 and WSL2 sessions around can make sense for this reason.  You can backup/clone your existing session (see `wsl --export` and `wsl --import`) and set the WSL version for a distro with `wsl --set-version`.
3. You might also consider sharing the Windows folder and mounting it via CIFS.  Reports are that this is much faster (although not as fast as ext4).  See [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4197) and the suggested workaround from EvilVir on July 4th.

Comment: Tazaf, if you'd like to incorporate the additional items from my answer into yours, I don't mind (and I can then delete my answer).  I wouldn't have seen this 20-day old question if you hadn't generated some new activity on it.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds That's very fair of you. I could update my answer to add the details, but I'd feel better if you were to submit and edit of my answer, so that you're at least somewhat credited for the additionnal information.

Comment: Ah, right - Fairly new to answering, so didn't realize that was an option.  I'll do that now.  Thanks!

Comment: I dont think you understand the issue, you are talking about the general slowiness. This is ng commands in particular. Where `ng g c ..` takes 40 seconds. Anything using `ng ..` hangs for 40s before running. It is not a file access issue, its something like accessing the network.

Comment: @run_the_race It is a matter of accessing the files stored on the Windows filesystem through the "network" between the Linux subsystem and the main system. So, it is related. And yes, it's an general issue of the WSL2 subsystem, and since `ng` comamnds usually manipulate the filesystem, there usage is subject to this problem. But if you have a better explanation, please feel free to submit another answer. I'm pretty sure I don't know all the intricacies of the issue.

Comment: @Tazaf I think you are splitting hairs. It's not just the file access is slower, it's that there is something long that tries to happen, then timesout. That is different to a slow read/write speed. After installing angular, opening a shell will take 40s due to it setting up the auto complete.

Comment: @run_the_race I reiterate that if you have a better and more accurate answer than the one I posted, then you should add it as an answer instead of debatting in the comments.
Still, the fact remains that moving the project files from the Windows filesystem to the WSL2 filesystem did solve my slowness issue when I had it, and apparently solved it for other people too.

Comment: `ng --help` or `ng version` both take about 40 seconds to run in WSL. All commands take at least that long.